# sql query not accepting a php variable

Tags: php, sql

I feel a little guilty about posting this because I posted a similar but different question before, but I couldn't figure out what the problem with this one is.

I am simply trying to run a SQL query with a PHP variable taking place of an integer value, but it doesn't seem to work; when I replace the variable with a simple number (like `1`) it actually works, so there's nothing wrong with the query itself.

When I put in the variable `$email_id` at the end, it does not work.

Can anyone point out what the problem might be?

Code:

```
$row = Db_DbHelper::query('select subject from system_email_templates where id = '.$email_id);
```

Comment: you should just look at the error message if a query 'doesn't work'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add single quotes around your PHP variable, so the updated code:

```
 $row = Db_DbHelper::query("select subject from system_email_templates where id = '".$email_id."'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't seem to work. I tried placing double quotes around single quotes (which is an opposite of what you've done) and it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    $sql = "select subject from system_email_templates where id = '".$email_id."' ";
    $row = Db_DbHelper::query($sql);
```

Comment: no, which is the strange thing. I checked the error log and it's clear

Comment: Well echo query and run it to your mysql tool,check query is ok.